# Rails filtering has and belongs to many databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have a user table that has and belongs to many tools.

so each user can have as many tools as they want and the tools can be associated with the user.

what i am trying to do is create a filter system so that on my main page people can click a selection of tools and it will show only users that have an association with those tools.

so it needs to brings back only users that have all of the skills someone has selected for instance someone who has Git and Jira , Not git or Jira

i can do it for one tool by using

```
if params["Confluence"]
        contractors = contractors.includes(:tools).where(tools: { name: "Confluence" })
end
```

i have tryed doing something like this

```
contractors = contractors.includes(:tools).where(tools: { name: "Confluence" , name: "Git", name: "JIRA Core" , name:"JIRA Software"})
```

but it only brings back the users with the last tool in the list. i have also tryed like this

```
    if params["JIRA Core"]
        contractors = contractors.includes(:tools).where( tools: {name: "JIRA Core"})
    end

    if params["JIRA Software"]
        contractors = contractors.includes(:tools).where( tools: {name: "JIRA Software"})
    end
```

however this does not work either. anyone have any ideas?

Comment: contractors.joins(:tools).where('tools.name = ?', "JIRA Core")

Answer (score 1):

**Check this out**

This is the case when you need contractors should at least one of the tools

```
contractors.joins(:tools).where('tools.name IN (?) ', ['JIRA Core','Git']).uniq

OR 

contractors.joins(:tools).where('tools.name = ?', "JIRA Core").uniq

OR
```

This is the case when you need contractors should have all the tools

param_values = ['JIRA Core','Git']

```
contractors.joins(:tools).where('tools.name IN (?) ', param_values).group('contractors.id').having('contractors.count = ?', param_values.count).uniq
```

Comment: That has got me closer to the result i need Thank you, However what this is doing is bringing back a instance of that user each time he has one of the tools, any idea where i could go from here?

Comment: @Adear Yes he will fetch the users having the one of the tools.... so you can get duplicate users instaces , so you could use use uniq

Comment: i would like it to display users that have all of those tools, any idea how that is done?

Comment: `param_values = ['JIRA Core','Git']`

`contractors.select('contractors.*, COUNT(contractors.id) AS count').joins(:tools).where('tools.name IN (?) ', param_values).group('contractors.id').having('contractors.count = ?', param_values.count)`

Comment: all im getting with the new solutions is  no such column: contractors.count and when i remove that it says about no such column: contractors.id do you know where im going wrong?

Comment: @Adear can you give your query, have you used both queries in comment section and in answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your params of tools should be the array of tools that are selected by the user

```
@tools = params[:tools]
```

Declare contractors array to which you will push by querying for each tool

```
@contractors = []

@tools.each do |tool|
  @contractors << Contractor.includes(:tool).where(tools: {name: tool.name})
end
```

and flatten to do .each in the view templates.

```
@contractors.flatten!
```

in Views:

```
<% @contractors.each do |contractor|%>
  <p><%=contractor.name</p>
<%end%>
```